# Why my website interface cannot connect to the firebase real-time database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to create a simple interface to check whether I can connect to the firebase real-time database or not. But unfortunately, it is not working.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCYidiTYtEPYlO4p1tpCrdPV3Ed726s4TY",
      authDomain: "test-4567f.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://test-4567f.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "test-4567f",
      storageBucket: "test-4567f.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "683153942498",
      appId: "1:683153942498:web:b6b713ebf4db0658"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    function writeData() {
      firebase.database.ref("User").set({
        name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
        age: document.getElementById("ageField").value
      });
      getData();
    }

    function getData() {
      firebase.database().ref('/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = childData['name'] + ", "
          childData['age'];
        })
      })
    }
  </script>
  <h3>Website</h3>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="nameField">
  <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="ageField">
  <button onclick="writeData()">submit</button>
  <p id="data"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

My data in the firebase is empty and I don't know what the problem with my simple code.

The error showed

[image]

Comment: Check your browser console for errors; that tells you what your (first) problem is.

Comment: It stated that "cannot read property 'ref' of undefined at writeData() and at HTMLButtonElement.onclick